# Wordpress only displaying home page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have tried to get my live website to a localhost environment. 
It looks like everything is working fine (admin panel etc).
The actual website on the other hand is not. I can see the default homepage but I cannot click on any links.

My htacess file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I tried to reset the Perma links to default as well.

Comment: Did you changed the domain name in the database (wp-options table)?

Comment: I found the issue, there was a plugin "Custom permalinks" Sorry my bad.

Comment: How do i delete this post  ^^'

Answer (score 0):

**Replace your live url to your local url using the below query**

UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://oldurl', 'http://newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://oldurl','http://newurl');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://oldurl', 'http://newurl');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://oldurl','http://newurl');

UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://newurl');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://newurl');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://newurl');